# How to make a three times smaller video from a large video as fast as possible with Handbrake?

Tags: video-conversion, matroska, handbrake

I have a good quality black and white old movie in MKV format of 11GB.

My intention is to keep the original and to create smaller versions for practical reasons when watching on various devices that imply copying to a USB flash drive, etc…

That's why I'm not mainly interested in keeping same quality, but in reducing size from 11GB to about 3GB-4GB (about 3 times) as fast as possible.

How to do that with Handbrake?

FWIW, I am in Linux but prefer Handbrake to something like ffmpeg in terminal because I like to see info on progress the way Handbrake shows it and because I want to test this program and learn how to adapt its use to my needs.

The output format is not important to me. The file has the following properties:

```
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 2
File size                                : 11.0 GiB
Duration                                 : 1 h 49 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 14.5 Mb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2017-09-12 21:14:03
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v15.0.0 ('Duel with the Devil') 64-bit
Writing library                          : libebml v1.3.5 + libmatroska v1.4.5
Cover                                    : Yes
Attachments                              : cover.jpg

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 1 h 49 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 14.3 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 15.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.287
Stream size                              : 10.9 GiB (98%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2623 d5b2374
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:-1:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x133 / me=umh / subme=9 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=24 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=34 / lookahead_threads=5 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=150 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=8 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=120 / keyint_min=61 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=120 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=18.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=15000 / vbv_bufsize=31250 / crf_max=0.0 / nal_hrd=vbr / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=3:1.00
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : E-AC-3
Format/Info                              : Enhanced Audio Coding 3
Codec ID                                 : A_EAC3
Duration                                 : 1 h 49 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 224 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 187.500 FPS (256 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 175 MiB (2%)
Language                                 : English
Service kind                             : Complete Main
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Comment: Speed might depend on other things. I vaguely remember a quicksync fork of handbrake that was impressively fast - you might be able to use another GPU API to get similar results

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Under "Official - General" presets there is a series of "very fast" ones. Testing them, I have found what I was looking for and posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My idea was to save 1 minute of the source movie and test on that 1-min file the different presets (including Giacomo1968's): that's a fast way to find the most preferable, before starting the several-hours long processing of the 11 GB file.*

---

Thanks to the other [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1609653/1039759) by @Giacomo1968, I know that x265 codec is not needed for old B&W movies, therefore I decided to use a x264 mp4 codec.

As one of my main concerns was *speed*, I have selected the preset under **General - Very fast 720p** (changed framerate to "as source", kept the default RF 23)

[image]

### **That gave me what I wanted: a file of 2.9 GB (down from 11) with 3.5 bitrate (down from 15).**

---

I have also tested the preset in the other answer with the 1-min file: the time was longer (maybe twice), the bitrate two times lower, the size was 7% smaller.

**I will mark the preset *General - Very fast 720p* as the solution here because it gives the desired size with greater speed and bitrate. The image quality is also much better, very close to the original.**

*Within the same preset* the quality, size and bitrate of the output can be increased by reducing the RF (and decreased by increasing the RF) *with the same processing speed*.

[image]

I have followed the rule from [here](https://www.winxdvd.com/resource/handbrake-constant-quality-settings.htm) about which RF to use:

```
Recommended constant quality settings (RF values) for H.264 (x264) and H.265 (x265) encoders:

• 480p/576p Standard Definition video: RF 18 - 22 is a suggested range.
• 720p High Definition video: RF 19 - 23 is a suggested range.
• 1080p Full High Definition video: RF 20- 24 is a suggested range.
• 2.7k/4k Ultra High Definition video: RF 22 - 28 is a suggested range.
```

Not following these rules gives unexpected/illogical results (output larger than input, low quality).

Answer (score 1):

### I used these preset settings recently to convert some classic black and white files in MKV format to 480p MP4 files.

#### Here are my notes and the preset settings.

---

Now 480p seems small and dinky and might be considered “crappy” by some. But these settings work great to reduce the file size of a large 1080pm black and white video to something smaller.

#### Less action in most any classic black and white film.

The reason why this works is old black and white films don’t have much camera action. Even the most action filled black and white film’s action is nowhere near the head spinning imagery fest most modern full color films are. So that naturally makes compression better.

#### Classic black and white films are grainier.

The only thing that is a real factor in old black and white films: They are incredibly grainy. So grainy that if you attempt to export a HQ video from a 1080p video source, much of the compression time will be spent trying to retain the grain. By scaling the dimensions down to 480p, grain is effectively removed without even having to use a grain detection algorithm.

#### x264 compression is the best compression format for black and white films.

Also, output is an MP4 is in x264 format. Many videos nowadays use x265 compression. That is a great video compression format, but only if the source video is color. The more image data x265 compression gets, the better the compression. But a black and white video has less color data than a full color video. My attempts to use x265 in the case of black and white videos results in videos that might actually be larger in file size compared to the source.

#### Audio compression.

Be careful here and you might want to double-check what audio is being converted — and how — when you do this. My settings attempt to deal with this but in some cases I had MKV files with multiple audio tracks and some of them did not convert but rather just were copied into the new file. In some cases these extra audio files accounted for 30% to 40% of the file size.

So all that said, here is my Handbrake preset for HQ 480p black and white transcended video output:

```
{
  "PresetList" : [
    {
      "AlignAVStart" : true,
      "AudioCopyMask" : [
        "copy:aac",
        "copy:ac3"
      ],
      "AudioEncoderFallback" : "ca_aac",
      "AudioLanguageList" : [

      ],
      "AudioList" : [
        {
          "AudioBitrate" : 160,
          "AudioCompressionLevel" : -1,
          "AudioDitherMethod" : "auto",
          "AudioEncoder" : "ca_aac",
          "AudioMixdown" : "stereo",
          "AudioNormalizeMixLevel" : false,
          "AudioSamplerate" : "auto",
          "AudioTrackDRCSlider" : 0,
          "AudioTrackGainSlider" : 0,
          "AudioTrackQuality" : -1,
          "AudioTrackQualityEnable" : false
        },
        {
          "AudioBitrate" : 640,
          "AudioCompressionLevel" : -1,
          "AudioDitherMethod" : "auto",
          "AudioEncoder" : "copy:ac3",
          "AudioMixdown" : "5point1",
          "AudioNormalizeMixLevel" : false,
          "AudioSamplerate" : "auto",
          "AudioTrackDRCSlider" : 0,
          "AudioTrackGainSlider" : 0,
          "AudioTrackQuality" : -1,
          "AudioTrackQualityEnable" : false
        }
      ],
      "AudioSecondaryEncoderMode" : true,
      "AudioTrackSelectionBehavior" : "first",
      "ChapterMarkers" : false,
      "ChildrenArray" : [

      ],
      "Default" : false,
      "FileFormat" : "av_mp4",
      "Folder" : false,
      "FolderOpen" : false,
      "InlineParameterSets" : false,
      "Mp4HttpOptimize" : false,
      "Mp4iPodCompatible" : false,
      "PictureAutoCrop" : true,
      "PictureBottomCrop" : 0,
      "PictureChromaSmoothCustom" : "",
      "PictureChromaSmoothPreset" : "off",
      "PictureChromaSmoothTune" : "none",
      "PictureCombDetectCustom" : "",
      "PictureCombDetectPreset" : "off",
      "PictureDARWidth" : 0,
      "PictureDeblockCustom" : "strength=strong:thresh=20:blocksize=8",
      "PictureDeblockPreset" : "off",
      "PictureDeblockTune" : "medium",
      "PictureDeinterlaceCustom" : "",
      "PictureDeinterlaceFilter" : "off",
      "PictureDeinterlacePreset" : "default",
      "PictureDenoiseCustom" : "",
      "PictureDenoiseFilter" : "off",
      "PictureDenoisePreset" : "light",
      "PictureDenoiseTune" : "none",
      "PictureDetelecine" : "off",
      "PictureDetelecineCustom" : "",
      "PictureForceHeight" : 0,
      "PictureForceWidth" : 0,
      "PictureHeight" : 480,
      "PictureItuPAR" : false,
      "PictureKeepRatio" : true,
      "PictureLeftCrop" : 0,
      "PictureLooseCrop" : false,
      "PictureModulus" : 2,
      "PicturePAR" : "auto",
      "PicturePARHeight" : 9,
      "PicturePARWidth" : 4,
      "PictureRightCrop" : 0,
      "PictureRotate" : "angle=0:hflip=0",
      "PictureSharpenCustom" : "",
      "PictureSharpenFilter" : "off",
      "PictureSharpenPreset" : "medium",
      "PictureSharpenTune" : "none",
      "PictureTopCrop" : 0,
      "PictureWidth" : 1472,
      "PresetDescription" : "",
      "PresetName" : "HQ 480 B&W",
      "SubtitleAddCC" : false,
      "SubtitleAddForeignAudioSearch" : true,
      "SubtitleAddForeignAudioSubtitle" : false,
      "SubtitleBurnBDSub" : true,
      "SubtitleBurnBehavior" : "foreign",
      "SubtitleBurnDVDSub" : true,
      "SubtitleLanguageList" : [

      ],
      "SubtitleTrackSelectionBehavior" : "none",
      "Type" : 1,
      "UsesPictureFilters" : true,
      "UsesPictureSettings" : 1,
      "VideoAvgBitrate" : 4500,
      "VideoColorMatrixCodeOverride" : 0,
      "VideoEncoder" : "x264",
      "VideoFramerate" : "auto",
      "VideoFramerateMode" : "vfr",
      "VideoGrayScale" : true,
      "VideoLevel" : "3.1",
      "VideoOptionExtra" : "",
      "VideoPreset" : "slow",
      "VideoProfile" : "high",
      "VideoQSVAsyncDepth" : 4,
      "VideoQSVDecode" : false,
      "VideoQualitySlider" : 25,
      "VideoQualityType" : 2,
      "VideoScaler" : "swscale",
      "VideoTune" : "",
      "VideoTurboTwoPass" : false,
      "VideoTwoPass" : true,
      "x264Option" : "",
      "x264UseAdvancedOptions" : false
    }
  ],
  "VersionMajor" : 42,
  "VersionMicro" : 0,
  "VersionMinor" : 0
}
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your advice, but in the end I have preferred my own solution. I have posted it as a separate answer and gave reasons for selecting it (including a comparison with your preset) but that seems to trigger some disapproval.